# Can a statement of interest be a narrative storytelling kind of style?

Tags: writing, statement-of-purpose

I'm doing this for a program. More specific is the prompt here:

> Share why you want to serve on this committee! Your statement of
> interest should describe your background, knowledge, and any
> experience that would add value to the committee’s work, and how your
> qualifications will contribute to the overall diversity. Please also
> include how you learned about this opportunity in your statement.

I kind of want to show when I started becoming interested by putting in a little story at the beginning then go on to explain my knowledge, experience, etc...

Comment: What does "program" mean? The text mentions a committee, what is this exactly for?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the "style" is less important than that you cover the points requested. If writing is an important part of the activities of committee members then it might be an advantage to use a narrative style. OTOH, if it is a strictly technical committee, populated by geeks, then something more "bullet-pointy" might be best to permit others to "check off" the requirements.

As in most writing, consider your audience.